# Validate multiple email with comma seperate in jquery validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I want to allow email address with last comma value like **aa@gmail.com,bb@gmail.com,** ***i want comma also in last***

Here is example for allow string in validation

I used

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("multiemail",function(value, element) {
        if (this.optional(element)) // return true on optional element 
         return true;
            var emails = value.split(/[,]+/); // split element by ,
            valid = true;
            
            for (var i in emails) {
                value = jQuery.trim(emails[i]);
                // value = emails[i];
                valid = valid &&
                        jQuery.validator.methods.email.call(this, $.trim(value), element);
            }
        return valid;
        },"Please enter a valid email address.");
```

but if i enter aa@gmail.com,bb@gmail.com, then its give me error like

> "Please enter a valid email address."

Comment: What is in each element of `emails` after you have split the incoming email?

Comment: i dont know this output ..pls help me out of here

Comment: `console.log(emails)` then see inspector output.

Comment: Well, you could `console.log` or `alert` each value at the start of the loop.

Comment: Just skip the validation if the email address is an empty string, but then you should also not use it further on.

Comment: when i console then i found  ["aa@asd.com", "bb@gmail.com", ""]